# Showing UIWebView modal for login page

Tags: uiwebview, uistoryboard, ios5

In my AppDelegate.m I'm using following code to show a modal UIWebView (a login page).

```
@synthesize window, viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (NotLoggedIn]) {
        window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
        viewController.view.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [window addSubview:viewController.view];
        [viewController viewWillAppear:YES];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];

        // continue with verification if login was successful
    } else {
        // show the maincontroller for the UIStoryboard
    }

    return YES;
}
```

when successfully logged in, the UIWebView shall disappear and the rootcontroller from the storyboard shall be displayed. How do I need to rewrite above code?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to present your login page modally from your main view controller's viewDidLoad method, e.g.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self presentModalViewController:loginWebViewController animated:YES];
}
```

where loginWebViewController contains your login page. On successful login, dismiss the modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should adopt the UIWebViewDelegate protocol, and determine if the login is successful or not in these delegate methods, then dismiss the ModalViewController or invoke removeFromSuperView of UIWebView.